# Lighting appears black/non-existent

Tags: rendering, lighting

Hey I've been trying to render a basic scene in Blender, when viewing the scene in the render display mode the lighting appears pretty normal but when I actually render my scene it appears almost fully black, might be missing something obvious but at this point I don't know how to solve this.

[image: Render Display]

This is how it appears in Render Display mode.

[image: Actual Render]

This is how it looks in the actual Render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object called "`skybox`"  hidden in preview, but renderable - can it block light from sun?

[image]

Look attentively in outliner. Object not marked with aye icon are invisible in preview, but they can be visible in render, if icon with camera is enabled (Like  "`skybox`" object).

Comment: @cegaton Actually, I've posted it here, because can't post comment via android app. But, also I sure that the answer of my question is "Yes", so that my comment can be considered as answer.

Comment: Oh my god, this is such a simple solution, I just assumed that if the eye was checked it would be invisible in the render aswell, shows how little I know, thanks!